# Remove foreign characters and gaps in window.location.hash

Tags: javascript, jquery, hash, window.location

I'm using post title for url hash, like this:

```
window.location.hash = news_title;
```

Yes, it works good but like this:

```
http://example.com/news.html#This%20Is%20Kul%C3%BCb%C3%BC%20%E2%80%93%20News%20Build
```

Because some titles contain spaces and special characters.

I tried that but its not working:

```
window.location.hash = project_name;
var hash = window.location.hash;
hash = hash.replace('%20', '-');
```

What should I do? Thanks!

Comment: See urldecode doc https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/decodeURI

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace needs a global option to do a replace all, and you should use decodeURIComponent (or decodeURI if you have slashes) first:

```
let hash = decodeURIComponent(window.location.hash).replace(/\s/g, '-');
```

Comment: Thank you but if I use `decodeURIComponent`, title getting with spaces. Like this: This Is News. But I need this-is-news.

Comment: After decoding try hash.replace(/\s/g, '-') - edited answer

Answer (score 2):

You are looking for `decodeURIComponent`

```
   var hash = decodeURIComponent(window.location.hash)
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/decodeURIComponent